# C++/CLI, I have a Byte[] and I need a char* to the first and last elements

Tags: c++-cli

I've been handed a `Byte[]` that contains a file.  I need to pass this to another method that is expecting two parameters, a `char*` to the beginning of the file and a `char*` to the end of the file.

I'm assuming I need to pin the array first so it doesn't get collected.  I don't imagine I can then just cast the first and last elements, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I just found out that you can create a `pin_ptr<unsigned char>` from such an array and then `reinterpret_cast` the result.

```
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinned = &buffer[0];
    unsigned char* unsignedBufferPtr = pinned;
    char* bufferPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(unsignedBufferPtr);
```

You can then use a reinterpret_cast on the result